# Kubernetes Ingress perform authorization before route, like api gateway

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, api-gateway, kong-ingress

It's possible to perform an authorization(rule-based like) into Kubernetes ingress(like kong, nginx).
For example, i have this:

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-bar
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.foo.bar
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /service
        backend:
          serviceName: service.foo.bar
          servicePort: 80
```

But before redirect to /service, I need to perform a call in my authorization api to valid if the request token has the rule to pass for /service.

Or I really need to use an API gateway behind ingress like a spring zuul to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ingress` manifest is just input for a controller. You also need an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/), an proxy that understand the `Ingress` object. Kong and Nginx is two examples of implementation.

[Nginx  Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) is provided from the Kubernetes community and it has an example of [configuring an external oauth2 proxy](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth/oauth-external-auth) using annotations

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
```

Comment: there are 4 types of authentication you can configure with Nginx Ingress Controller for which documentation you can find in [nginx controller github repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth)

Comment: perfect, nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url worked!